# implementing a pagewise side scrolling app drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have been able to create a simple app drawer as shown in the first image. I have used packagemanager to create an ArrayList mApplications, which is used as a data source for the gridview.

```
mGrid.setAdapter(new ApplicationsAdapter(this, mApplications));
```

Image One (Have Done). http://i42.tinypic.com/kdabgy.png

Now, i want to change the layout of this to function like a pagewise side scrolling app drawer much like in samsung touchwiz, ics launcher, iphone etc. using the same arraylist. What would be the simplest way to do this?

I have tried many things like Viewflipper, ViewPager etc, but all of them seem way too complex to implement. for example, a viewpager needs "views" as its children. how can i change the arraylist into grid and then into pages/views for the view pager

Image (Want to achieve). http://i949.photobucket.com/albums/ad335/rastallpaul/galaxyapps.png

Answer (score 0):

take a look at those to links

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/29/android-switching-screens-by-dragging-over-the-touch-screen/

Comment: yes, but but how can i get this to display the contents of my ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> which is a list of application names and their icon

Comment: sry never used grid view But i thing that grid view is more likely to contain UI elements and lot data you might wanna look in to modifying a list view